# What transformation is required to find a unique solution of this problem instead of multiple solutions?

Tags: convex-optimization, eigenvalues, nonlinear-optimization, eigenvector

$$
\max\limits_{\mathbf{f},\ \|\mathbf f\|=1 } \log_2\left(\prod^K_{i=1} \  \frac{ \mathbf{f}^H {\mathbf E} (\mathbf{W}_i, \Theta, \tau_i) \mathbf{f}} { \mathbf{f}^H \mathbf{G}_i ( \mathbf{W}_i, \Theta, \tau_i) \mathbf{f} }  \right)  
$$

For the product of Rayleigh quotients in the above problem,
solution $\psi_i\in (M\times1)$, corresponding to the largest eigenvalue $\zeta_i$, for the $N \times N$ matrix pairs $E$ and $G_i$ is obtained. So, for $K$ product terms, $K$ solutions instead of one is obtained.

How to find an unique solution for this problem?

Comment: May I say that if what was in this question is the LaTeX in your own articles, please, please learn good coding style and improve how you set mathematics,

Comment: yea. Sure. Thanks .